# intranet portal for the project

Tags: share

I would like to setup a portal for my development team to share the ideas, reports, documents, images, etc. Something similar to MS SharePoint but free/open source.

Can you please share what do you guys use for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com)

Answer (score 1):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) and [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) would be my top two picks, depending on whether or not you wanted ticketing integrated.  Don't forget, also, that MediaWiki has a robust plugin ecosystem, so anything you wanted to add above and beyond wiki and discussion functionality might well be available.

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) is another good pick - I don't love it quite as well as Trac, but it's much easier to set up on the shared host where I keep my project management tools.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/)